# Show that the roots of P' lie in the same half plane as the roots of P

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, polynomials, roots, conformal-geometry

The problem statement is:

Part(a)

Assume P(z) is a non-constant polynomial with all of its roots in some half plane H.  Show that the derivative P'(z) must also have all of its roots in H.

Part (b)

Show that the roots of P' always lie within the closed convex hull of the set of roots of P.

The hint given is:

After obvious reductions of the problem, look at the behavior of $\frac{P'}{P}$ on the complementary half-plane.

My thoughts:

So I think that, whatever half-plane H that we have to work with, we can always just look at $P(e^{i\theta}z)$, which has its zeros in the UHP, for a suitable rotation by angle theta.

Now we can just show that $P'(e^{i\theta}z)e^{i\theta}$ also has its roots in the UHP -- and then undoing the rotations shows that both P and P' had its roots in the same half-plane H.

Using the hint regarding looking at the complementary half-plane, we then want to show that P' does not vanish in the LHP (we already know P doesn't vanish in the LHP, by assumption.)

Again following the hint we look at P'/P in the LHP and show that it does not vanish.  I am stuck at this point.  How can I proceed?

And regarding part(b) what is a "convex hull"?  I am guessing that the answer to part (b) is immediate, after figuring out part(a).

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

Let $$P(z) = c \prod_{1\le k \le n} (z - z_k)$$

then $$P'(z)/P(z) = \sum_{1\le k \le n}\frac{1}{ (z - z_k)}$$

Therefore, if $z$ is a root of $P'$ that is not a root of $P$ ( i. e a simple root) then we have 
$$\sum_{1\le k \le n}\frac{1}{ (z - z_k)}=0$$

Let's show that $\sum_{1\le k \le n}\frac{1}{ (z - z_k)}\ne 0$ for any point not in the relative interior of the convex hull of the $z_k$ and different from all $z_k$'s.  Indeed, consider such a point $z$. Then the nonzero complex numbers $(z-z_k)$ have all arguments inside a halfplane, and so will the numbers 
$\frac{1}{z-z_k}$, so their sum cannot be $0$.

Comment: Hi @orangeskid, thanks so much for your answer.  How do you go from a product to a summation?  I have P'/P as a product / product, using the fact that complex polynomials always split into linear factors.  Also, what is a convex hull?  Thanks,

Comment: Ooh @orangeskid did you use log? :-) hmmm...

Comment: @User001: Yes, more or less;  or calculate $P'$ and get a sum of $n$ terms, each term a product of $n-1$ factors, then divide by $P$. Convex hull of a (finite) bunch of points is the smallest convex polygon containing all the points. It will have vertices among these points, but some points might be inside ( but not outside).

Comment: Hi @orangeskid, I see that, for z in the LHP, the difference $(z-z_k)$ will clearly have negative imaginary part.  Inverting gives us numbers with *positive* imaginary part - this is easily verified.  And so the terms in the sum will always have positive imaginary part, and we are done.  So the question about the closed convex hull is simply to note that since the roots of P' also lie in the UHP, then they will also fit inside of the same convex polygon that contains the roots of P?

Comment: And one last thing, if you don't mind:  I started by looking at the rotation of the preimage points, so that P conveniently takes its zeros in the UHP -- do I need a translation mapping at all?  I am thinking that rotation is enough... thanks, @orangeskid,

Comment: @User001: it is easier to look at the case of the roots of $P$ being in some half plane ( not necessarily upper), and so if $z$ is outside then all the $z_k-z$ are there, $1/(z_k-z)$ are in the symmetric one, and so the sum is not zero. You could also do rotations but you can nail it in one argument.

Comment: Ok got it - thanks so much for your help, @orangeskid.  Have a great night :-)